# using same code to specific blocks of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 7 different blocks of checkboxes in a form, with about 8 checkboxes in each block.

I'd like he user to able to tick a box at the top of each block which would then tick(and untick) the block underneath it.

I've trying to put my own code together, but being a beginner, i am struggling to get it to work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#checkall").click(function()             
        {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            county = $(this).val();
            countyfind = $("input").find('.' + county);
            countyfind.each(function()
            {
                this.checked = checked_status;
            });
        });                 
    });

    </script>
```

Heres the check box at the top of a block:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="east_anglia" value="east_anglia"> &nbsp;<h4 class="postcoderegion">East Anglia</h4>
```

...which would tick the following:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="served_areas0" name="served_areas0" class="east_anglia" value="AL" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
```

Any help/guidance would be very useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right, except that once you've identified the county, your find is wrong.
Just change this line:

```
countyfind = $("input").find('.' + county);
```

to this:

```
countyfind = $("input." + county);
```

The `.find()` looks for *child* elements matching the selector, but the input element **itself** has the desired class, not any child of the input.

Comment: Sean also has a good point - if you want to have multiple checkall inputs then you'll need to follow his advice too

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work -- once you change `#checkall` to `.checkall` and your `id="checkall"` checkboxes to `class="checkall"`.

The issue is that ID must be unique in the document - and if there is more than one ID with the same value in the current document the result in undefined.  And since jQuery uses `document.getElementById` for IDs, it doesn't actually find anything for your first DOM query - which means no click event gets registered.

In addition, you need to find inputs with the appropriate class, rather than elements that have the appropriate class *and* are children of inputs. Change `countyfind = $("input").find('.' + county);` to `countyfind = $("input." + county);` (See @nocache's answer).

However, there is an even better way to do things.  Rather than creating `n` event listeners (where `n` is the number of `.checkall` boxes you have) create a single [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (either on `body` or on a containing element) to listen for clicks and react to the appropriate clicks.

So instead of:

```
$("#checkall").click(function() {
    // Do things here
});
```

Try:

```
$("body_or_selector").delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
    // Do things here
});
```

Then, once you have the event, you can work with [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to find the checkboxes below it and check them.

```
var $target = $(event.target);
var checked_status = $target.prop("checked");
$target.closest("container_for_you_checkboxes").
        find(":checkbox").
        prop("checked", checked_status);
```

**See:** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAKDF/1/)

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, changed those two things, but still doesn't do anything when ticking the .checkall box?

Comment: @Justin - I missed the second part of the issue - see @nocache's answer for the second issue. (I'll add it to my answer as well.)

Comment: thank you both, works great! two really useful lessons learned there, so thanks again..

Comment: @Justin - glad we could help! I've updated my question with a bit more information as well.